# Calling SOAP API inside WEB API causing synchronous issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I am calling third party SOAP API inside WEB API causing the synchronous issue.

Code needs to be execute completely for each loop, inside for each I have SOAP API call, but it is stopping in between and restarting with beginning for same value loop.

Same value loop is calling twice, I am not sure what is happening, its strange issue. I have more stuff inside loop I can not share that, here is scenario i created for same.

```
EX: 
     items = ["a","b","c","d"]
     foreach(string s in items)
    {
      console.log("Start: "+s)
    // Call SOAP API create something ***(in this part of logic I called reusable class)***
    console.log("Complete: "+ s)
    }

Output: Start: a
        Start: a
        Complete: a
And so on
```

This is coming randomly for one or another item.
please help me for this.

Comment: Can you provide more details? According to your existing information, I can't reproduce your question.

Comment: I am calling SOAP API inside Web API, which is running bit long 1 to 2 min, some times the flow is moving here and there, which is not synchronous way.

Comment: Are you calling the asynchronous method of the soap API? If you are calling the asynchronous method, do you use await?

Comment: no it is synchronous only.

Comment: Sorry, based on the information you provided, I have not reproduced your problem, can you provide more?